# Techniques of Sobolev spaces in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I learned a proof of Hodge decomposition (in particular harmonic integral) in Griffith and Harris's book. It was proven by techniques of Sobolev spaces. But I wonder when I use techniques of this type in studying (Complex) Algebraic Geometry. Are there any applications as well as Hodge decomposition?

(For example, I heard deformation theory uses non-linear PDE ...)